# Is there a way to implement Material's multi-select on Cards using standard Flutter or a package?

Tags: flutter, material-design

Is there a way to implement multi-selection of "Larger selections" in Flutter, like cards or images? When the items go into selectable mode, a circular checkbox appears in the upper left corner. It's used in Google Photos.

I don't see it in the Flutter docs.

It's in the Material Design 3 spec here: [Foundations > Interaction > Selection > Larger selections](https://m3.material.io/foundations/interaction/selection#97a46ad7-9596-4959-ada4-22b9cbb2cc0c)

Comment: Is it a possible solution to add cards/images and the circular checkbox in a stack?

Comment: Yes, there are several ways I could custom-build this functionality, but I was looking to see if anyone was aware of something off-the-shelf, since Flutter support for Material is so good, and this is part of the Material spec.